# IE 8 crashes when using regex with to validate currency

Tags: jquery, regex, internet-explorer

I have written a bunch of code to have a valid entry for Spend amount (`32.4554`, `234,324.34`, etc.).  I have additionally written code to limit the user from entering more than 13 digits (excluding `.` and `,`).

All of this works perfectly in Firefox. But in IE 8, after the number of digits exceeds 13, if a letter is entered, Internet Explorer hangs and crashes!  While debugging I noticed it faulting at the regex line, but the same regex works fine until that limit of 13 isn't crossed! Regexperts, please! Show me the light!

```
function isIncorrectSpend(cubeCurrencySpend) {  
    if(!(/^([1-9]*[0-9]*,?[0-9]*)* (\.[0-9]*)?$/.test(cubeCurrencySpend))) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function isLongerThanThirteenDigits(cubeCurrencySpend) {
    cubeCurrencySpend = cubeCurrencySpend.replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\./g, "");
    if(cubeCurrencySpend.length>12) { 
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

jQuery("input#minval").keyup( function() {
    if(isIncorrectSpend(jQuery("input#minval").val())) {
        jQuery("input#minval").val("");
        alert("please enter correct spend value");
    }        
});
jQuery("input#minval").keypress( function(e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if(isLongerThanThirteenDigits(jQuery("input#minval").val()) && (code > 47 && code < 58)) {
        alert("Please enter a number less than 13 digits");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

Comment: Its not IE's fault. The regex: `/^([1-9]*[0-9]*,?[0-9]*)* (\.[0-9]*)?$/` as stema correctly points out, suffers from [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am quite sure this is a case of [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). Your regex has too many possibilities to check, till it can fail.

The problem is this part

```
([1-9]*[0-9]*,?[0-9]*)*
```

and I am quite sure it is not doing what you expect it to.

This will match the same stuff, but will fail much quicker:

```
/^[1-9]*[0-9,]*(\.[0-9]+)?$/
```

it is still allowing stuff like 1,,,,,,,.123, but much better than yours. If you want to disallow such things, you need to clarify your requirements.

Comment: @ridgerunner, of course you are correct, I forgot to delete the opening bracket.

Answer (score 0):

You could also alter the regex to combine both the length and validity check.

```
function isIncorrectSpend(cubeCurrencySpend) {  
     return !/^(?!0)(?:\d[,\.]*){1,13}$/.test(cubeCurrencySpend);              
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes you wish to validate a decimal "number" which meets the following criteria:

### Definition of a "Number"

- There must be at least one digit and all digits must be decimal (from 0 to 9).
- Both the integer and fractional parts are optional, but one or the other must be present.
- The fractional part, if present, may have any number of digits but is always preceded by a decimal point.
- If the integer part has more than one digit, the leading digit must not be zero.
- If the integer part has more than three digits, commas may be used to separate the integer into digit triplets.
- The number may begin with an optional sign, either a plus `+`, or a minus `-`.
- Whitespace is not allowed.
- An exponent part is not allowed.

Given the above requirements here are some valid and invalid numbers

### Valid "Numbers":

```
0
0.
.0
0.0
1
+1
-1
1234
123456
1,234
12,345
123,456
123,456.7890
```

### Invalid "Numbers":

```
0FA92      // Invalid digit. Must be 0-9.
0123       // Multi-digit integer must lead with non-zero.
.          // Must have at least one digit.
1,23,4     // Commas must separate triplets of digits.
12345,678. // Missing comma.
+  10      // Whitespace not allowed.
1.2E34     // Exponents not allowed.
```

Here is a regex (first presented in commented, free-spacing mode format using Python's handy raw string syntax) which matches a number meeting the above requirements:

### Regex to validate a "number"

```py
r"""
^          # Anchor to start of string.
[+\-]?     # Optional sign.
(?=\.?\d)  # Must have at least one digit.
(?:        # Optional integer part. Either...
  [1-9]    # A sequence of digits w/no commas.
  \d*      # (but first digit is not zero.)
|          # or an integer having commas...
  [1-9]    # First digit is not zero.
  \d{0,2}  # 1,2 or 3 digits ahead of 1st comma.
  (?:      # One or more comma + 3 digits.
    ,      # Comma separates
    \d{3}  # digit triplets.
  )+       # One or more comma + 3 digits.
| 0        # or integer part may be just zero.
)?         # Optional integer part.
(?:        # Optional fractional part.
  \.       # Dot separates
  \d*      # zero or more fraction digits.
)?         # Optional fractional part.
$          # Anchor to end of string.
"""
```

Here is a JavaScript function which implements the above regex:

### function isValidNumber()

```js
function isValidNumber(text) {
    var re = /^[+\-]?(?=\.?\d)(?:[1-9]\d*|[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:,\d{3})+|0)?(?:\.\d*)?$/;
    if((re.test(text))) return 'true';
    return 'false';
}
```

Note that you should not be trying to validate the number until after the user has finished entering the entire number. Calling a validation function for each and every keypress (as your code above appears to be doing) is not good practice IMHO.